# Dynamically setting the width of a container based on item widths returned from an Angular component

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular JS 1.6 & UI Router for routing.  I'm trying to create a layout that is completely horizontal.  It's basically a "feed" of content coming from an Angular service and it uses a component to loop through each item and output it.

My question is how do I dynamically calculate the sum of all item widths and apply it to my container. Here is an example of the html.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-row">
    <keyfeed>
      <!-- NG repeat results -->
      <div>Column 1</div>
      <div>Column 2</div>
    </keyfeed>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.container` div is positioned absolute and the `.container-row` div has an arbitrary 10,000px applied to it to make sure the content never wraps (horizontal scrolling site).  Instead of setting `.container-row` to 10000px I want to loop through the items and calculate the width for the container.  This presents a few problems.  This component shows up on multiple routes, so I'd need this calculated on UI route change.

If I were to do this in jQuery it would look something like this

```
$(window).load(function() {
   // This works only on window.load which isn't helpful for angular...

   var containerWidth = 0;
   $('.c-key').each(function() {
     containerWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
   });

   $('.container-row').css({
    'width': containerWidth,
    'min-width': '100vh'
    });
});
```

This doesn't work even inside the run function. Any ideas on how I should tackle this using components and UI Router?

Comment: I'd recommend doing the same with an attribute type directive. place it on the same tag as the ng-repeat.

Comment: Why you need to calculate width? Can not simple css solve this? May be you can create plunk demonstrating problem -- seems like u are trying to invent wheel...

Comment: @PetrAveryanov i think he may have other things in the parent container, but he still want it's width to fit the container-row's width.

Comment: The columns are 300px wide and they need to be inline infinitely to the right.  I don't know of a better way to do that but setting overflow-x on the parent container, but in order for them to stay inline the column widths need to match the column wrapper width. @PetrAveryanov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a attribute directive, remove the fixed width for the container-row, then get it's width using angular jquery alias, something like this:

```
angular.element('container-row').scrollWidth
```

then apply it to it's parent container:

```
angular.element('container').css({
    'width': theNewValue,
});
```

The selectors depend on where and how you place the directive.

Comment: If I remove the width, it'll return to me the width of the browser window not the sum of the children divs.  Trying as a directive though.

Comment: Putting this in a directive works with window.load, but it's only temporary.  Meaning it only works on the first page load. As soon as I browse to another route with that same component it doesn't work (since the page isn't loading again)

Comment: I ended up using a directive on container-row and putting the calculation inside of a setTimeout function.  Thanks!